# Xaml ThemeResource imagebrush binding with custom control property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently working on a windows UWP application in which a I use theme resource dictionary.

I have in my theme dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <!-- Light Theme resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        ...
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Hamburger" ImageSource="Assets/Images/DarkHamburger.png"/>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- Dark Theme resources -->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        ...
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Hamburger" ImageSource="Assets/Images/LightHamburger.png"/>
        ...
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

and a custom control property

```
public ImageBrush toggleButtonImage
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(toggleButtonImageProperty) as ImageBrush; }
        set { base.SetValue(toggleButtonImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty toggleButtonImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("toggleButtonImage", typeof(ImageBrush), typeof(HomeHeaderControl), null);
```

At the end if I write this, it works

```
<HomeHeaderControl.toggleButtonImage>
     <ImageBrush  Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/Images/LightHamburger.png"/>
</HomeHeaderControl.toggleButtonImage>
```

But the theme resource binding is not working

```
toggleButtonImage="{ThemeResource Hamburger}"
```

Other bindings are working except the ImageBrush.
Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Absolute path and Bitmap Image

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
<!-- Light Theme resources -->
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
    ...
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Hamburger" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/DarkHamburger.png"/>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
<!-- Dark Theme resources -->
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
    ...
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Hamburger" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/LightHamburger.png"/>
    ...
```

Comment: The [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension) page explicitly mentions Brushes, so could you please explain why you think an ImageBrush can't be used?

Comment: This is incorrect. Theme resource *does* work with `ImageBrush`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all
I found the missing. I was using relative path in ImageSource.

> I used ->
>       `<ImageBrush x:Key="Hamburger" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/DarkHamburger.png"/>`
>    and it fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure? I use relative path n it's working fine.

Comment: Is your theme resource dictionary in another project?

Comment: No, just in a folder. Thank you for your help

Comment: OK then relative path definitely works. I will create a sample for you later today.